# Is there a the obligation to be MeChadesh Divrei Torah

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, torah-study

The mitzvah of learning Torah is well known. But what about being MeChadash Chidushei Torah, innovating Torah thoughts? Does such an obligation exist? or is it enough that I learn what is written without ever coming up with my own innovative explanations?

Are there any well known *essays* on this subject?  (I stress essays and not just one liners found in various seforim.)

Answer (score 3):

In Hilchos Talmud Torah by the author of the Shulchan Aruch HaRav [1:1](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/1.htm) (and brought again in [2:2](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/2/2.htm)) the Rav quotes based off the Zohar (Part 1 page 12b) the Taz ([O.C. 545 s.q. 13](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2901) regarding writing Chiddushei Torah on Chol Hamoed) and others "and after you acquired in Torah each person according to his skill... to be Michadeish Halachos rabos - innovate a lot of halachos (in [1:5](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/5.htm) he uses the term Chidushei Halachos Liayn Kaytz (to no limit!))

In his other work the Tanya ([Igeres Hakodesh 26](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/tanya/4/26.htm) (page 145a) the Alter Rebbe writes "every Jew is able to reveal secrets of wisdom and to discover a new insight whether it be in laws or in homiletics in the revealed or in mystical... **indeed one is obligated to**" (and the Alter Rebbe goes on to write a whole paragraph explaining this idea according to Chassidus).

See also [Sefer HaSichos 5749 part 2 page 468ff](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16011&st=&pgnum=75&hilite=) where the the Lubavitcher Rebbe discusses this topic.